# Two independent weak convergence sequences have dependent limit?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n\Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n\Rightarrow Y$ as $n\to\infty$, where all these $X$ and $Y$ are well defined random variables and $\Rightarrow$ is the convergence in distribution.

Could you give me an example in which $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply $X_n,Y_n$ i.i.d. (non-trivial) r.v. and $X=Y=X_1$?

Comment: What about $X$ and $Y$ i.d.d. and $X_n=\frac{X}{n}$ and $Y_n=\frac{Y}{n}$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: @Surb I don't think that is a counterexample?

Comment: @nejimban Why $Y=X_1$?

Comment: So that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: @nejimban I mean how can you construct $X_n$ and $Y_n$ with the same limit $X_1$ ? Not just assume that $Y=X_1$.

Comment: I don't understand. Nothing prevents me from taking $X=Y=X_1$. We are talking about convergence *in distribution* here. The distributions of all variables in play are the same, so convergence in distribution trivially holds. But of course $X$ and $Y$ are not independent because they are equal as random variables.

Comment: @nejimban Of course you could take $Y=X_1$ and I understand your consideration. But you could also take $Y$ to be the independent copy of $X_1$, right? So, what's the essential difference? I can't have any insight from your answer, sorry.

Comment: But you want the limit $Y$ to be **not**  independent of the limit $X$, correct? That's precisely why I choose $Y=X_1$ and $X=X_1$.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the whole concept of convergence in distribution. The fact that $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to}X$ and $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\to}Y$ but for each $n$, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent tells us nothing about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

The use of characteristic functions deals with all real-valued random variables. Let each pair of $Z_n=(X_n,Y_n)$ be independent (i.e. $X_n$ is independent of $Y_n$). Then for all $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have
$$E[e^{i\xi \cdot Z_n}]=E[e^{i\xi_1 X_n}]E[e^{i\xi_2Y_n}]\to E[e^{i\xi_1 X}]E[e^{i\xi_2Y}]$$
Let $Z^{(1)} \sim X,Z^{(2)}\sim Y$ be s.t. $Z^{(1)}$ is independent of $Z^{(2)}$. Then define $Z=(Z^{(1)},Z^{(2)})$. We have
$$E[e^{i\xi \cdot Z}]=E[e^{i\xi_1 Z^{(1)}}]E[e^{i\xi_2 Z^{(2)}}]=E[e^{i\xi_1 X}]E[e^{i\xi_2Y}]$$
So $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a pair of independent rvs each with respective distribution $\sim X,\sim Y$. However, $(X,Y)$ might have any distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer! Although $X$ and $Y$ may be dependent, we can always find an independent copy $Z$ such that $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow Z$ (your $Z$). So, we can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Am I understanding this correctly？

Comment: @MikeHWANG No, I don't think you can assume that they are independent. Let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y=-X$. Let $(X_n,Y_n)_n$ be any sequence of independent pairs where $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X,Y_n\stackrel{d}{\to} Y$. Then $(X_n,Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\to}$ bivariate standard normal with zero correlation. However $X$ and $Y$ have perfect negative correlation.

Comment: Can we make the assumption like this: in your example, we change the limit of $X_n$ as $X^\prime$, i.e., $X_n\Rightarrow X^\prime$ and $Y_n\Rightarrow Y$ where $X^\prime$ is an independent copy of $X$. So, we throw away the $X$, and use $X^\prime$ instead, and we assume $X^\prime$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: At this point you just assume that $(X,Y)$ are independent from the beginning. In this case, we indeed have $(X_n,Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\to}(X,Y)$. @MikeHWANG

Comment: @MikeHWANG if this helped with or solved your problem, don't forget to upvote or accept! :)

Answer (score -1):

Let $a$ be such that $F_X(x)$ is continuous at $a$, and $b$ be such that $F_Y(x)$ is continuous at $b$. Then $F_{X_n}(a)\to F_X(a)$, $F_{Y_n}(b)\to F_Y(b)$. On the other hand,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n\le a,Y_n\le b)=\mathbb{P}(X_n\le a)\ \mathbb{P}(Y_n\le b)
$$
by independence. As a result, the LHS of the above
$$
F_{X_n,Y_n}(a,b)\to F_X(a) F_Y(b)
$$
so if $F_{X,Y}(a,b):=F_X(a)F_Y(b)$ then
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n\le a,Y_n\le b)\to F_{X,Y}(a,b)\quad\text{as }n\to \infty
$$
and thus the pair $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in distribution to a random variable whose CDF is given by $F_{X,Y}(a,b)$, and given its product form, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

The only thing which remains to consider is the case when $F_X(x)$ is not continuous at $a$ (and similar for $Y$).

Comment: Thank you! I like your answer. But I have another question: How about the case $X_n$, $Y_n$, $X$ and $Y$ are all continuous random variables ? In this case, the distribution functions are continuous.

Comment: Then what I wrote gives a full proof, no more arguments needed, I think.